# Choosing the 'WHERE' clause in Designer View in Visual Studios 2012

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I am facing an issue right where i am supposed to make use of the datagridview in a windows form application.

I have created a datagridview in my page, and i want to retrieve all the values relating to that one particular user.

Right now.. using the datagridview designer view this is what i have. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKgq8.png

I have a static variable in a class that contains the current user that is logged in.

However i cannot add my static variable (in this case.. LoginInfo.username) to the back of the query.

Is there some function in VS2012 that i do not know that allows me to add a static variable at the end of the query using the designer view? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so. This tool is for direct SQL-only-queries to the database. You should considering *CommandBuilder-instances. Please bare in mind, that approaches like this open up possibilities related to SQL Injection.

Comment: yeah i suspected there's no easy way out to this.. My last resort would be to change the design of the application that would not require the gridview..